# Unable to remove rows with specific cell value python openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm having a weird issue where the logic and code tells me it should work but it does not.

My code is below

```
import shutil, sys
from distutils.version import StrictVersion
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('testing.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
x = ws.max_row
y = ws.max_column

for r in range(1,x+1):
        for j in range(1, y+1):
                d=ws.cell(row=r,column=j)
        if str(d.value).lower() == "false":
                ws.delete_rows(r)

wb.save("test_1.xlsx")
```

The excel is made out of 5 columns, A B C D E
first Row have titles so can be ignored
A2 has time, B2 has name C2 has username,D2 path, E2 contains value of either TRUE or FALSE

The point of my script is to look at all cells and if the value of FALSE is found it will remove that row.
So for example row 10

01/01/1999 John Smith JohnS /path/ FALSE
This should be removed as it contains FALSE or more specifically E10 has FALSE.
The TRUE FALSE values only appear in column E so for the sake of speed we could specify that we are only interested in column E but any row. I have done that in other version.

To the problem
The problem is that my testing excel has total of 25 rows and columns A B C D E as stated above but the script only removes 5 rows that had value FALSE. Also it seems the script removes the rows that contain FALSE at random so in my testing excel there are total of 10 rows with FALSE cell.
the usernames in order will be 
t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10
but the script just now removed
t1, t3, t5, t6, t7, t9
which looking at it now seems I have an issue with logic and its checking odd numbers

EDIT
it seems that if I repeat the loop enough times it will remove all rows that contain FALSE

current code that's working

```
import shutil, sys
from distutils.version import StrictVersion
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('testing.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
x = ws.max_row
y = ws.max_column

for r in range(1,x+1):
        for j in range(1, y+1):
                d=ws.cell(row=r,column=j)
        if str(d.value).lower() == "false":
                ws.delete_rows(r)


for r in range(1,x+1):
        for j in range(1, y+1):
                d=ws.cell(row=r,column=j)
        if str(d.value).lower() == "false":
                ws.delete_rows(r)

for r in range(1,x+1):
        for j in range(1, y+1):
                d=ws.cell(row=r,column=j)
        if str(d.value).lower() == "false":
                ws.delete_rows(r)

for r in range(1,x+1):
        for j in range(1, y+1):
                d=ws.cell(row=r,column=j)
        if str(d.value).lower() == "false":
                ws.delete_rows(r)

wb.save("test_1.xlsx")
```

its not pretty so any tips will be appreciated

Comment: Could you please post a visual representation of your excel file?

Comment: https://ibb.co/kKD2r8

It seems I fixed my issue, my pasting the same loop x3 it removes what I want, for some reason at the start it removes every 2nd so if you paste the loop two more times eventually it removes it all. This is one ugly way and help to make it better is appreciated

Comment: It seems its still not working, giving bigger excel it removes both False and True fields

Comment: I've added an attempt to what you might be looking for. Also It might be better if you insert the image into your question. Makes it easier to view for future readers.

Comment: Please note that every time you remove a row you will move all the cells in rows below it which will affect any counting you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's the problem of the indentation, try this:

```
import shutil, sys
from distutils.version import StrictVersion
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('testing.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
x = ws.max_row
y = ws.max_column

for r in range(1,x+1):
    for j in range(1, y+1):
        d=ws.cell(row=x+1-r,column=j)
        if str(d.value).lower() == "false":
            ws.delete_rows(x+1-r)
            break

wb.save("test_1.xlsx")
```

and I change the row number from `r` to `x+1-r`, which means iterating the rows from the last to the first(so that when one row is deleted, the rest rows won't be affected), and It's necessary to break the inner loop(cause the looping row is deleted, you can't loop this row any more)

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for this, your answer works as expected. Did not think of removed cells going up and the whole loop will be removing cells that once had FALSE value but now might have TRUE

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook

# open workbook and get active worksheet
wb = load_workbook('original.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

# extract headers from row 1
headers = [cell.value for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=1) for cell in row]

# want to keep headers by default
new_rows = [headers]

# go through every row(>=2) except headers
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2):
    values = [cell.value for cell in row]

    # create dictionary of row 
    row_dict = dict(zip(headers, values))

    # only append if 'enabled' is True
    if row_dict['enabled']:
        new_rows.append(values)

# create a new workbook and sheet to write to
new_wb = Workbook()
new_ws = new_wb.active

# iterate though rows and columns of nested list
for row, line in enumerate(new_rows, start=1):
    for column, cell in enumerate(line, start=1):

        # write new cell to output worksheet
        new_ws.cell(row=row, column=column).value = cell

# save output workbook
new_wb.save('output.xlsx')
```

Which gives a new *output.xlsx* file with all rows containing `FALSE` in the `enabled` column removed.

It first creates a dictionary for each row, and if the key `enabled` is set to `True`, keep that row. At the end it iterates through all the rows and writes them seperately back to the output file.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t1.py", line 9, in <module>
    headers = [cell.value for (cell,) in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=1)]
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Worth saying that the test excel I was using doesn't have many rows but the intend of this script is to be used on excels with rows of 1500+

Comment: @k3mp3r See updated answer. If you need it to handle many rows, it may be worth changing to a `pandas` solution.