# Remove rows from Excel file using Python without losing formatting

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

I have a large XLSX file. One of the columns contains numerical values. I have a list of some of those values. I need to delete the rows which contain the values from the list, leaving the rest of the XLSX file intact. The solution shouldn't depend on win32com or VBA. It should work on a non-Windows OS without an Excel installation.

I tried using Pandas. This works well for removing the rows using the drop method. However, when the result is written to a new XLSX file, formatting such as bold and italics is lost (replaced by Pandas' formatting). Reportedly, OpenPyxl is better than Pandas in keeping the formatting. However, OpenPyxl's delete_rows method doesn't seem to support using a list of values, only indexes of the rows, which is not very good for me.

the spreadsheet:

```
number  text
12      abc
34      def
56      ghi
78      jkl
90      mno
```

the code:

```
data = pd.read_excel('deleteRowsTest.xlsx', index_col=0)
data.drop ([34, 78], inplace = True)
data.to_excel('deleteRowsTestOut.xlsx')
```

The file deleteRowsTestOut.xlsx contains the remaining rows. This is good, but formatting such as bold and italics is lost. I would like to keep it.

Comment: you might want to try [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead of `pandas`

Comment: @randomfigure Thank you, but is there an OpenPyXL alternative to Pandas' DataFrame.drop? The delete_rows in OpenPyXL only accepts row index and number of rows. No way to feed a list of cell values to delete_rows. There is a similar problem described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51510669/unable-to-remove-rows-with-specific-cell-value-python-openpyxl/51514173 but it still deals with single values, not a list of values.